# problem in UIAlet

Tags: iphone

I am create my first iphone app however facing lots of problems now.. I am trying to use an alert window which has options of Yes and No. WHen i click on no it should remain on the same screen however when i click Yes it should take me to another screen but i am not able to do the Yes part. My code looks like this..

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressedid)sender
{
NSString *TITLE = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"Do you want to add the ingredient to your Grocery list"];
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" 
message:TITLE 
delegate:nil
cancelButtonTitle:@"No" 
otherButtonTitles:@"YES",nil];
```

So when i click yes it should take me to another screen. How should i do that?

Pls help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need UIAlertViewDelegate

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

for more detail read following tutorial

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/uialertview/

Answer (score 0):

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Game Over" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Quit" otherButtonTitles:@"Restart",nil];
    alert.tag = 1;
    [alert show];
    [alert release];

## pragma mark AlertView delegate methods

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
  if (alertView.tag == 3) {
      if (buttonIndex == 0) {
          exit(0);
      }
      else {
          [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
          [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
          [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
          [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.view cache:YES];
          [self viewWillAppear:YES];
          [UIView commitAnimations];

  ```
      appDelegate.winningAmount = nil;
      encylCount = 0;
      googleCount = 0;
      mGoogleButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
      mEncyclopediaButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
  }
  ```

  }

}